# To get ID request from URL and read the value from database in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have and URL = http://localhost:8080/***_HRM/#/epmsTeam/**:id**.

From that id place i need to read the value in angularjs and get the data from database and it should be displayed as particular id.

please see the images that I have tried and by default I have given an ID as$scope.empId = 394;.

[image: see here the image here]

Here by clicking on particular Employee I need to get details of that particular id.

Answer (score 0):

Use below steps  :

1) Your controller -

```
   $scope.empId=$stateParams.id;
```

2) Then call api using -

```
  $http.get('/urlbyId'+$scope.empId).success(function(response){

      console.log(response.data)   
  })
```

Note : Replace url 'urlbyId' by your real one

Comment: Instead of $stateParams I have used $routeParams, It worked. thanks for the solution.